# Various Regex Validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js

I'm new to regex. I have an array (call it arr1) with assorted values. I am trying to validate that it has the following format for its elements with arr1[x] provided as an example

```
arr1[x] = "item1, item2, item3, item4, item5":

item 1 - "abcdef" (variable number of letters) or "abcdef asdf" (variable number of letters separated by one whitespace character)
item 2 - "abcdef" (variable number of letters) or "abcdef asdf" (variable number of letters separated by one whitespace character)
item 3 - "12345678" (eight digits)
item 4 - "123 456 7890" (telephone number with 3 digits followed by 3 digits followed by 4 digits with two whitespace characters as shown)
```

Here is a snippet of what I have for phone number validation (not sure how the second line works - got it from a different SO thread):

```
function f(s) {
  var s2 = (""+s).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var m = s2.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please show us the code for what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex to account for all your cases:

```
^(?:[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?|\d{8}|\d{3} \d{3} \d{4})$
```

Use it with `i` option, e.g.:

```
var re = /^(?:[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?|\d{8}|\d{3} \d{3} \d{4})$/i; 
if (re.exec(s) !== null) {
    return true;
}
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jS9eE0/1).

```js
var re = /^(?:[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)?|\d{8}|\d{3} \d{3} \d{4})$/i; 
var str = 'abcdef';
if (re.exec(str) !== null) {
    alert(true);
}
```